# Send reply with Gmail api with just send permission

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

My goal is to send a follow-up email using the Gmail api.

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending), you must supply a message-id when trying to send a reply.

However, it seems like the only way of getting a message-id is by calling the messages endpoint, which requires access to the users inbox.

**Is there any way of sending a follow up email without asking for inbox permissions?**

One hack I thought of was to forward the email to the recipient. However, that doesn't seem possible without the message-id either.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access private user data with out the owner of said datas permission.

The Gmail api allows you to access a users Gmail account, send emails from the user themselves is just one of the things it can do.

You need to use Oauth2 to authenticate the user once they have consented to your application accessing their data you will then be able to find the message-id.

I wonder how you would know you need to send a follow up email if you dont have access to the email in the first place.

Comment: Would the -1 please comment i would be happy to improve the answer explaining to this person why what they would like to do cant be done.